Decidable fragment of second-order logic
By a fragment of second-order logic (SO) I mean a recursive (= computable) subset of the set of sentences of SO. Such a fragment  $L$ is decidable, if there is an algorithm which determines whether a given sentence of $L$ is satisfiable, i.e., has a model.
Given two logics $L_1,L_2$, we say that they have the same expressive power, if for each sentence $\varphi$ of $L_1$ there is a sentence of $L_2$ which is equivalent with $\varphi$ (defines the same class of models), and vice versa.
Question: does there exist a decidable fragment of SO which has the same expressive power as SO?
Some remarks: First, if we do not require that a fragment needs to consist of a recursive set of sentences, then clearly there exist such a fragment. Secondly, if we replace SO with first-order logic (FO), the answer is no, because the set of valid sentences of FO is RE. Thirdly, if we restrict our attention to finite models, then there is such a fragment. For more discussion on this, see this note.

By sentences $\phi_i$ being equivalent in $L_i$, you mean something like $SO \models \phi_1 \leftrightarrow \phi_2$? Or equi-satisfiability?

@MartinBerger I mean semantic equivalence, i.e., for each model $M$ we have that $M \models \phi_1$ iff $M \models \phi_2$.

What does $M$ range over in $M \models \phi_i$?

@MartinBerger It ranges over the class of all models (= structures) over the (common) vocabulary of $\phi_1,\phi_2$.
